# Retrieve Azure Static Web App Default Custom Domain in ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-static-web-app, azure-custom-domain

I am deploying an Azure API management app through an ARM template. As a part of my requirement, I need to retrieve the static web app default domain to configure APIs to receive requests through an ARM template.

For now, I am doing manually by following below link, but I need to automate same kind of steps through ARM template deployment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis-api-management#configure-apis-to-receive-requests

we can fetch azure function app default key using below script, which is something similar I am looking for same to retrieve static web app custom domain name.

`listKeys(concat(resourceId(variables('functionSite-ResourceGroup'),'Microsoft.Web/sites', 'FunctionTestAppName'), '/host/default'), '2016-08-01').functionKeys.functionKeys.default`

Comment: Azure static web app sites are not directly supportive for the retrieval of the custom domain information. It needs to be managed externally. Instead of ARM, you can use PowerShell or CLI to retrieve the information and then pass it to the code. @PavanKumar GVVS

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, retrieval of default custom domain value from a static web site is not directly doable as the communication between custom domains and web sites will be managed externally. You can use either `PowerShell` or `CLI` to retrieve the default value easily using related commands.

**CLI:**

```bash
az staticwebapp show --name "jahnavistatic" --resource-group "resource_group" --query defaultHostname -o tsv
```

[image]

**PowerShell:**

```
$static=Get-AzStaticWebApp -ResourceGroupName "resource_group" -Name "jahnavistatic
$static.defaulthostname
```

[image]

If your requirement is still with the ARM template, then you can follow the workaround given below.

You can pass the above `PowerShell` or `CLI` commands directly to the [deployment scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template#sample-templates) in ARM template and reference the template later in the `outputs` block.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/outputs?tabs=azure-powershell#linked-templates) to check how to link the templates in `outputs` block.

Another alternative is to set the default custom domain value as a user defined value in the `parameters` block and retrieve it in the `outputs` block by referencing that related `parameter`.

I tried a sample template for the above workaround by referring to the [github template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/web-app-custom-domain-and-ssl/azuredeploy.json) and was worked as follows.

```bash
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location for all resources."
            }
        },
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "latestjank"
            }
        },
        "sku": {
           "type": "String",
           "metadata": {
            "description": ""
           }
        },
          "skuname": {
           "type": "String",
           "metadata": {
            "description": ""
           }
        },
        "customHostname": {
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "mynewhost"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "appServicePlanName": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'),'-asp-', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/staticsites",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                    "Tier": "[parameters('sku')]",
                    "Name": "[parameters('skuname')]"
                }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostnameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/', parameters('customHostname'))]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/staticsites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "hostName": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[reference(parameters('customHostname'))]"
        }
    }
}
```

[image]